# No data is displayed error in Fusioncharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, fusioncharts

I used ajax to render the chart.I have two files index.php ,selectchart.php.In index.php, i have used ajax to render chart.

```
<div class="chart-area">
                   <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>

                   <div id="chart-mon"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>
```

Above, chart-1 div used to annual report,then we choose month the chart will display as per choose.

```
              </div>
```

```
<p><select class="btn btn-light btn-icon-split" id="country" name="country">
<option>--Select Month--</option>
              <option value="01">JAN</option>
              <option value="02">FEB</option>
              <option value="03">MAR</option>
              <option value="04">APR</option>
              <option value="05">MAY</option>
              <option value="06">JUN</option>
              <option value="07">JUL</option>
              <option value="08">AUG</option>
              <option value="09">SEP</option>
              <option value="10">OCT</option>
              <option value="11">NOV</option>
              <option value="12">DEC</option>
              </select></p>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#country').change(function() {
        var selectedcountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        //alert(selectedcountry);

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "selectchart.php?country="+selectedcountry,
                data : selectedcountry,
                success: function(result)
                   {
                   $("#chart-1").hide();
                   //$("#myDiv").show();
                   alert(result);
               var myChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myThird", 400, 300, "json", result);

              myChart.render("chart-mon");

                    }
                  });

    });
</script>
```

I have alert the result `[objectoject]` showed.But in `chart-mon` no data is diplayed showed.but I run the selectchart.php

selectchart.php

```
include("includes/fusioncharts.php"); 

$selectdata = $_REQUEST['country'];

   $dbhandle = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
   if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
    exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
   }

        $strQuerymon = "SELECT name, amount FROM income WHERE month = '$selectdata'ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 10";
       $resultmon = $dbhandle->query($strQuerymon) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");


        if ($resultmon) {

            $arrDatamon = array(
                "chart" => array(

                  "showValues" => "0",
                  "theme" => "zune"
                )
            );

            $arrDatamon["data"] = array();
            while($rowmon = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmon)) {
            array_push($arrDatamon["data"], array(
                "label" => $rowmon["name"],
                "value" => $rowmon["amount"]
                )
            );
            }


            $jsonEncodedDatamon = json_encode($arrDatamon);

            echo $jsonEncodedDatamon;

header('Content-type: text/json');


        }



{"chart":{"showValues":"0","theme":"zune"},"data":[{"label":"washing","value":"1000"},{"label":"cleanin","value":"444"},{"label":"rwr","value":"333"},{"label":"sample","value":"300"},{"label":"werew","value":"33"},{"label":"demo","value":"10"}]} these values are displayed.[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I think you passed wrong:

**Instead of it**

var myChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myChartId" , 400, 300, "json", "result");

**You have to pass:**

var myChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myChartId" , 400, 300, "json", **result**);

Because **result(it's variable)** is your response which is came from your selectchart.php page.

Comment: Can you please share whole page with required files?
I need simple HTML file(with all reference) with static JSON output result.

Comment: Please confirm are you using which version for FusionChart?
https://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery-charts?framework=jquery
New version syntax:
https://i.imgur.com/Iyxz19D.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/PKagiXC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If your chart shows a "No data to display" message, it could be the following scenarios:

Your XML/Json data doesn't contain any data that could be plotted by FusionCharts. In this case, your XML just contains the  or  tags without any data between them.

You might be using a single-series chart SWF and providing data in multi-series format or vice-versa. In this case too, you'll get "No data to display" message.

In some Dual Y Combination charts, you need to provide atleast one data-set for both the axis. Otherwise, you'll get a "No data to display" message.

```
    <?php
include("includes/fusioncharts.php");

$columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2d", "ex1", "100%", 400, "chart-1", "json", '{
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
    "subcaption": "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
    "xaxisname": "Country",
    "yaxisname": "Reserves (MMbbl)",
    "numbersuffix": "K",
    "theme": "candy"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Venezuela",
      "value": "290"
    },
    {
      "label": "Saudi",
      "value": "260"
    },
    {
      "label": "Canada",
      "value": "180"
    },
    {
      "label": "Iran",
      "value": "140"
    },
    {
      "label": "Russia",
      "value": "115"
    },
    {
      "label": "UAE",
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "label": "US",
      "value": "30"
    },
    {
      "label": "China",
      "value": "30"
    }
  ]
}');

$columnChart->render();
?>
```